# How to get result detail of export Cloud Datastore？

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I have an app which stores user data in GCP Datastore.
I have made a cron job that is scheduled to export the data in Datastore using the instructions given [here](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/schedule-export).

Now, I want to get the results and finished time when this job fails.
(Not cron but job moved by cron)

How do I get the result detail of the export Cloud Datastore？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scheduled datastore exports (and imports) can be long-running operations, so they have support for [asynchronous execution](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/export-import-entities#async-flag) and [progress monitoring](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/export-import-entities#long-running-operation).

Basically when you launch the operation you get an operation id:

> For example, when you start an export, the Cloud Datastore service
>   creates a long-running operation to track the export status. Here's
>   the output from the start of an export:
>
> ```
> {
>   "name": "projects/[YOUR_PROJECT_ID]/operations/ASAyMDAwOTEzBxp0bHVhZmVkBxJsYXJ0bmVjc3Utc2Jvai1uaW1kYRQKKhI",
>   "metadata": {
>     "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.datastore.admin.v1.ExportEntitiesMetadata",
>     "common": {
>       "startTime": "2017-05-25T23:54:39.583780Z",
>       "operationType": "EXPORT_ENTITIES"
>     },
>     "progressEntities": {},
>     "progressBytes": {},
>     "entityFilter": {
>       "namespaceIds": [
>         ""
>       ]
>     },
>     "outputUrlPrefix": "gs://[YOUR_BUCKET_NAME]"
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> The value of the name field is the ID of a long-running operation.

You can then use the operation ID with [`projects.operations.get`](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/admin/rest/v1/projects.operations/get) in the [operation Admin API](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/admin/rest/latest/projects.operations) to obtain its completion time and result URL:

> This example output shows a recently completed export operation.
>   Operations are accessible for a few days after completion:
>
> ```
> {
>   "operations": [
>     {
>       "name": "projects/[YOUR_PROJECT_ID]/operations/ASAyMDAwOTEzBxp0bHVhZmVkBxJsYXJ0bmVjc3Utc2Jvai1uaW1kYRQKKhI",
>       "metadata": {
>         "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.datastore.admin.v1.ExportEntitiesMetadata",
>         "common": {
>           "startTime": "2017-12-05T23:01:39.583780Z",
>           "endTime": "2017-12-05T23:54:58.474750Z",
>           "operationType": "EXPORT_ENTITIES"
>         },
>         "progressEntities": {
>           "workCompleted": "21933027",
>           "workEstimated": "21898182"
>         },
>         "progressBytes": {
>           "workCompleted": "12421451292",
>           "workEstimated": "9759724245"
>         },
>         "entityFilter": {
>           "namespaceIds": [
>             ""
>           ]
>         },
>         "outputUrlPrefix": "gs://[YOUR_BUCKET_NAME]"
>       },
>       "done": true,
>       "response": {
>         "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.datastore.admin.v1.ExportEntitiesResponse",
>         "outputUrl": "gs://[YOUR_BUCKET_NAME]/2017-05-25T23:54:39_76544/2017-05-25T23:54:39_76544.overall_export_metadata"
>       }
>     }
>   ]
> }
> ```

I'm not entirely certain how you'd distinguish just the failed jobs, though, I imagine something different would show in the `response` field.